# How do I create a child Akka2 actor when all I have is an ActorRef to the parent?

Tags: scala, akka

In need to create an Akka2 actor (derived from UntypedActor) as a child of an existing actor (also derived from UntypedActor). The only reference I have to the parent actor is an ActorRef.  Is there any way to do this?  I'd like to call the parent's UntypedActorContext.actorOf() method, but don't know how to get a reference to it using the Akka API.  Is there a better way of accomplishing my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the code of the parent actor? You could for example add a handler for a message of type `Props` in your parent and create the child there. It is not possible to get the context outside of the actor class.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force someone to conceive against their will. Your actor needs to receive a message to which it responds by creating a new actor and send you the ref to that actor.